# JavaFX Populate ComboBox from MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, combobox, scenebuilder

I am using Java Fx and Scene builder, and my code runs without exceptions, but the combobox remains empty, and I can't understand why. I set identity ID and OnAction field but still it doesn't works. Here is my controller:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage; 

public class AdaugareSediuController {

    @FXML
    ComboBox<String> meniu;

    public void meniuCombo() throws SQLException{

        try {

            if(Conexiune.conexiuneBd !=null){
                String query = "SELECT * FROM maginfo";
                PreparedStatement dindb = Conexiune.conexiuneBd.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rezultate = dindb.executeQuery();

                while (rezultate.next()) {
                    String Nume = rezultate.getString("nume");
                    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Nume);
                    meniu.getItems().addAll(list);
                }

                dindb.close();
                rezultate.close();   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Conexiune.conexiuneBd` is not null?

Comment: Did you try basic  debugging ? For example adding some simple printouts  in the right places.

Comment: @c0der :  thanks, i try but the printout is not executed. What can i do now?

Comment: Add the print code to the code posted. (You can add the printout result as comment, for example: `System.out.println(Conexiune.conexiuneBd); // prints null`